ROS2 Topic/Node Communication Between Container and Local Machine- Ros2:Humble:22.04
Before I explain my problem, I have already made sure of the following:

BOTH the container and my machine are on rmw_fastrtps_cpp
Both the container and my machine are running the same version of ros2 humble
both the container and my machine are indeed on the same ROS Domain Id
my docker container has network mode as host

So I’m trying to use an ORBSLAM3 docker container while running a simulation for my robot locally. I have used an example between the ORBSLAM3 Container and a Clearpath gazebo simulation which was also in a container. But now I’m trying to run my personal simulation locally (not within a container), but I’m running into this weird issue. What’s happening is that whenever I launch my ros2 nodes both locally and in the container, I can see the topics from the nodes launched, but I do not get information from echoing the topics across the separate terminals (container/local runs). This is where it gets weird though. While all of the topics are visible, the nodes aren’t always visible, and it will toggle between the group of nodes that were launched based on stopping and starting the ros2 daemon. Even within the same terminal sometimes when I launch the gazebo sim it won’t show me the node list before I restart the daemon.
I am happy to answer any question, but I’d really appreciate some help with figuring out what’s going on since I’ve been stumped!
For reference since a lot of mentioend changes online haven't gotten me anywhere, this is my docker-compose.yml for the orbslam3 container that I have been using:
services:
  orb_slam3_22_humble:
    image: walle-orb-slam3-humble:22.04
    volumes:
      #full dev
      - /dev:/dev:rw
      #full media
      - /media:/media:rw
      #Time
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:rw
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:rw
      #ros-workspaces
      - ./container_root/:/root/
      - ./orb_slam3_ros2_wrapper/:/root/colcon_ws/src/orb_slam3_ros2_wrapper/
      - ./slam_msgs/:/root/colcon_ws/src/slam_msgs/
      # - ./ORB_SLAM3/:/home/orb/ORB_SLAM3/
      # For running with local machine
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm # Share Memory
    privileged: true
    network_mode: host
    ipc: host
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    environment:
      - DISPLAY
    entrypoint: /bin/bash

I really appreciate any insight that I can get from this amazing community. Thank you for the help ahead of time. And if you have any questions I will answer them asap!
